# firebase authentication error while i try to sign up with email and password

Tags: firebase, authentication

i trying to authentication with firebase but i face to some problem
[this is my problem ...i trying to sign up with email and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUxal.png)

```html
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
}
```

this is my dependencies\
tnks a lot!